# How to send bitmap from Android to java Tomcat?

Tags: java, android, maven, tomcat, kotlin

I want to send bitmap using POST method from android app to tomcat server. After the bitmap compressing I create an byteArray, and then I'm using Base64 encoder do encode it to String.

After receiving the request on server side I'm doing this:

```
        byte[] decoded = Base64.decodeBase64(encodedImage);
        ByteArrayInputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(decoded);

        BufferedImage bufferedImage = null;
        try {
            bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(stream);
            ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "bmp", new File("output_bmp.bmp"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

and I'm receiving error:

```
javax.imageio.IIOException: Error reading PNG image data
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.png.PNGImageReader.readImage(PNGImageReader.java:1345)
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.png.PNGImageReader.read(PNGImageReader.java:1614)
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1448)
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1352)
    at TestImage.main(TestImage.java:31)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.fill(InflaterInputStream.java:240)
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:158)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:286)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:195)
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.png.PNGImageReader.decodePass(PNGImageReader.java:1119)
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.png.PNGImageReader.decodeImage(PNGImageReader.java:1223)
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.png.PNGImageReader.readImage(PNGImageReader.java:1338)
    ... 4 more
```

Maybe there's a problem with the way I compress my file before sending it?

```
bitmapPicture.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, COMPRESSION_QUALITY, byteArrayBitmapStream)
```

Comment: Your subject is wrong. You are sending a .png to the server. That you created the .png from a bitmap is irrelevant. Well... if the .png was ok...

Comment: `Maybe there's a problem with the way I compress my file before sending it?` You should also show code until you have a base64 string that you finally send.

Comment: `javax.imageio.IIOException: Error reading PNG image data` You did not indicate where and how you read png data.